# Split file into multiple workbooks and save in separate folders

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel files with following worksheets.

City1
City2
City3
City4
City5      and so on till 47 sheets

The file destination is "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CityData\"

How could I split file into individual sheets and place them in the folders of same names as the name of sheets . The folders do not exist and I want to create the folders automatically. The folders should be created as subfolders of the above destination folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Sub SplitSheets()
 Const FolName = "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CityData\"
 Dim ws as worksheet
 for each ws in worksheets
        ws.copy
        Mkdir folname & ws.name
        activeworkbook.saveas folname & ws.name & "\" & ws.name & ".xlsm",52
        activeworkbook.close
  next ws
   end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to split a workbook into separate sheets.

```
Sub Splitbook()
'Updateby20140612
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You can copy and move files using the code below.

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
'This example copy all files and subfolders from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If ToPath already exist it will overwrite existing files in this folder
'if ToPath not exist it will be made for you.
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\your_from_path\"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\your_to_path\"    '<< Change

    'If you want to create a backup of your folder every time you run this macro
    'you can create a unique folder with a Date/Time stamp.
    'ToPath = "C:\your_to_path\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

You could certainly make it more dynamic, if you want to sweep multiple files into multiple different folders.  I think the best way to do that would be to list the folders in a column, and then loop through that list of items.  Something like this would do the trick.

```
Dim r As Range '-- if you don't declare it as a range type you get a variant type as default
Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop
Set r = Range("A1:B10") '-- substitute your range as per your example
For Each c In r '-- you could also use r.cells
    MsgBox c.Value '-- pass to your function instead of a call to the Message Box
Next
```